# Effect of print("") in a while loop in julia

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I encountered a strange bug in julia. Essentially, adding a print("") statement somewhere sensibly changes the behavior of the following code (in a positive way). I am quite puzzled. Why?

```
xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

cmds = [`sleep $x` for x in xs]

f = open("results.txt", "w")

i = 1
nb_cmds = length(cmds)
max_running_ps = 3
nb_running_ps = 0
ps = Dict()

while true
    # launching new processes if possible
    if nb_running_ps < max_running_ps
        if i <= nb_cmds && !(i in keys(ps))
            print("spawn:")
            println(i)
            p = spawn(cmds[i], Base.DevNull, f, f)
            setindex!(ps,p,i)
            nb_running_ps = nb_running_ps + 1
            i = i+1
        end
    end
    # detecting finished processes to be able to launch new ones
    for j in keys(ps)
        if process_exited(ps[j])
            print("endof:")
            println(j)
            delete!(ps,j)
            nb_running_ps = nb_running_ps - 1
        else
            print("")
            # why do I need that ????
        end
    end
    # nothing runs and there is nothing to run
    if nb_running_ps <= 0 && i > nb_cmds
        break
    end
end

close(f)

println("finished")
```

(Indeed, the commands are in fact more useful than sleep.)

If the print("") is removed or commented, the content of the conditional "if process_exited(ps[j])" seems to never run, and the program runs into an infinite while loop even though the first max_running_ps processes have finished.

Some background: I need to run a piece of code which takes quite a long time to run (and uses a lot of memory), for different values of a set of parameters (represented here by x). As they take a long time, I want to run them in parallel. On the other hand, there is nearly nothing to share between the different runs, so the usual parallel tools are not really relevant. Finally, I want to avoid a simple pmap, first in order to avoid loosing everything if there is a failure, and second because it may be useful to have partial results during the run. Hence this code (written in julia because the main code doing actual computations is in julia).

Comment: `print` is [asynchronous](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/networking-and-streams/) (for performance reasons) and yields. Maybe try `@sync print("")` instead? If that fixes your problem then I'll post this as an answer.

Comment: In fact my problem is already "solved" by adding the print("") (even without @sync). However, I do not understand why, hence my question.

Comment: Then your problem is the opposite: you want asynchronous behaviour (so a task switch can occur), and print provides that. I will post an answer soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bug, though it might be surprising if you are not used to this kind of asynchronous programming.

Julia is single-threaded by default and only one task will run at once. And for a task to finish, Julia needs to switch to it. Tasks are switched whenever the current task yields.

`print` is also an asynchronous operation and so it will yield for you, but a simpler way to do it is `yield()`, which achieves the same result. For more information on asynchronous programming, see [the documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/parallel/).